# Better to not use Core Data for ease of thread safety?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I have an app that is currently built on Core Data and has multiple threads with multiple NSManagedObjectContexts. It's a music app so there is always stuff running on the background threads that needs to not interfere with the main thread and vice versa.

So far I've been slowly chipping away at all sorts of deadlock & thread safety issues, but frankly I'm hitting a wall in trying to keep MOCs in sync and have them not block threads, and nothing access entities that have been deleted etc.

My question is this:
If I were to ditch Core Data and just create some custom NSObjects to keep track of properties would that make these kind of issues simpler? Is it possible to access the NSObjects from multiple threads (without causing deadlock etc) so that I wouldn't have to maintain several copies and sync them? Or will I still face similar challenges?

I'm pretty new to objective-c so i'm really looking for the easier solution rather than the most sophisticated. Any links to good designs patterns for this sort of thing also appreciated!

Comment: Are you using `NSFetchedResultsController`? Have (Can) you tried using dictionaries as your request results? What level of synchronization is required between you contexts?

Comment: This is a mac app but I've used arraycontrollers. There are many instances where I need to access what's in core data via code in multiple threads though. Not sure what you mean about dictionaries? Syncronisation-wise, essentially I have one data source that needs to always be in sync across 3 MOCs (1 parent, 2 child)

Comment: Have you thought about placing a single managed object context on a private queue and accessing it asynchronously from the rest of your app? I've never had particularly tough concurrency requirements from core data, but if I did, I'd probably look at that first.

Comment: The reason I'm avoiding this is that I want to separate interacting and changing the objects (which can happen with a small delay) from a background thread that is just reading data and playing music, and thus has it's own MOC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rephrasing the question: *"Would we be better off ditching a framework where the engineers, whose sole focus is on creating said framework, have spent countless hours working on that framework's concurrency model to instead roll our own concurrency model, starting from scratch?"*

Concurrency is hard.

Rolling your own means tackling all the problems that Core Data has tackled already (including *accessing state from multiple threads without deadlocking and/or requiring many copies of the data*) and then adding on whatever unique twists you need for your app.   The team that wrote Core Data has thought quite deeply about the subject, to the point that there is an entire set of [documentation devoted to it](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) (with the APIs to back it).

So, certainly, there is quite likely a concurrency model that would be highly specific to your application that would be considerably more efficient than using Core Data, but you are going to end up re-inventing the persistency patterns Core Data currently offers you *and* you'll need to engineer said concurrency model from the ground up.

So, no, there is no easy way out.

Given that it is a music app, I can fully appreciate how difficult the concurrency issues can be.  Latency is obviously a huge issue.    You'll need to ask a more specific architectural/design question to really glean much insight beyond the above.

For example, what granularity of data are you persisting via Core Data and what is the frequency of change of said data?  Is the model of said data relatively optimal?  Etc.etcetc...

---

Or, with a concrete example:

Say you have a `Note` class that describes a note to be played.  Say that note has properties like `pitch`, `volume`, `duration`, `instrument`, etc...

Now, imagine your background thread needs to set `pitch` and `duration`.

Without thread synchronization of some kind, how would the consuming thread know that the editing thread is done editing?

Comment: The data isn't updated too frequently – nearly all changes are based on user interaction, i'm not tracking any kind of temporary state etc in the core data. However, when it does change I need those changes to be reflected across the other MOCs instantly, and that seems to require an interaction between threads. If I were to use subclasses of NSObject across threads would they not deal with being accessed from different threads without me needing to implement a way to serialise everything that accesses or alters them?

Comment: First, you should understand why atomicity does not guarantee thread safety (http://www.friday.com/bbum/2008/01/13/objectivce-c-atomic-properties-threading-andor-custom-settergetter/).  Now, if all of your data is completely unrelated to other data elements *and* is of a type that supports lockless atomicity (i.e. ints, floats, bools, and nothing more complex), then you *might* be able to get away without thread synchronization primitives.   That, though, is exceedingly unlikely.   So, Yes, you are still going to have to think about thread interaction / concurrency issues.

Comment: OK cool thanks, that really helps to get an understanding of what the issues are. I'm definitely going to step back and think this through a bit but I think I will have a go at a prototype without Core Data at least. Hopefully it will be easier to get my head around it and learn by dealing with these things more directly, even if I do go back to Core Data later on.

Comment: @bbum "The team that wrote Core Data has thought quite deeply about the subject". How time the team have spent to develop Core Data ;) ? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @samir Core Data is rooted in EOF which was rooted in DBKit which was born out of things like OPP and Firehouse.  It has a direct lineage to the roots of object-relational mapping technologies and many people contributed to it for many years at a time.  Over CD's specific lifespan, much thought -- and supportive implementation -- has been given to concurrency issues.  Creating your own persistency layer is to throw out nearly 25 years of active development work. Certainly, there are reasons to do so, but that can't be discounted.

Comment: @MarkWheeler Definitely a useful approach.  If you haven't with CoreData, look into how objects can be faulted between managed object contexts.  This is generally very fast, but still may not be as  fast as a hand rolled solution specific to your problem.